# Is there a way to make GitHub Pages download bower dependencies?

Tags: github, bower, github-pages

I have a HTML page in a GitHub repo, which I would like to serve using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/). The page depends on some 3rd party libs which are noted as bower dependencies.
Is there a way to make GH Pages resolve bower dependencies? I'd prefer to not commit all the files.

Comment: Not sure wh this is VTC'd as "primarily opinion based". Its a yes/no question, and it has one definite, opinion-free answer: No, you can't.

Comment: @Polygnome that's because I edited the question to be more boolean-like. Before it read something like "What is the preferred way of deploying pages on GitHub Pages with bower dependencies"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It runs *Jekyll*, and only Jekyll, and only supports the plugins contained in the `gh-pages` gem. Bower is run on node.js. So the only way to do this is to *resolve the dependencies locally*, commit everything and then push.

In order to keep your branches somewhat clean, you could use a `source` (or whatver name you prefer) branch which only contains the needed sources and make your changes there. Once you have done your changes, merge the `source` branch into `master`, then resolve the dependencies again (if you changed them, or updates are available), commit and push the master branch.

This leaves you with a quite clean `source` branch, but also has all dependencies in you need resolved in the `master` branch.

Comment: This is the way to go, I guess. I'm now having bower_components commited in the gh-pages branch. Changes are only done in the master branch and then merged onto the gh-pages branch.